# error convert this data to date("HH:mm a"),("dd MM") and ("yyyy").how to divide it into sections :D

Tags: java, android

error(java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Nov  2 2017 09:44:00:000AM")

This is my code i use this on fragment

```js
String tanggal = dataObject.getString("tgl_periksa");
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSa");

DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = null;
try {
     date = readFormat.parse( tanggal );
} catch ( ParseException e ) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
String formattedDate = "";
if( date != null ) {
   formattedDate = writeFormat.format( date );
}
```

Comment: I think I understand the question, but the title confuses me. Why and how do you want what divided into sections?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your readFormat pattern to it:

```
DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSa")
```